# Show hidden elements inside overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple steps next to each other, some of them are hidden because of `overflow:hidden`. I want to show these hidden steps on reaching them.

Example from right to left: the numbers after the column are hidden

```
5       4    |   3       2       1
```

On reaching step 4 it should be shown and 1 should be hidden and vice-versa.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('next').onclick = function(){
    var active = document.querySelector('.active');
    active.classList.remove('active');
    active.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');

    //Show next steps
    if(document.querySelector('.active').getBoundingClientRect().right < 0){
      document.querySelector('.parent').scrollRight = 1000;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('back').onclick = function(){
    var active = document.querySelector('.active');
    active.classList.remove('active');
    active.previousElementSibling.classList.add('active');

    //Show previous steps
  }
}
```

```css
body{
    direction: rtl;
}

.parent{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
}

.child{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    background: grey;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.active{
    background: red;
}

.next{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.back{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span class="child active">1</span>
    <span class="child">2</span>
    <span class="child">3</span>
    <span class="child">4</span>
    <span class="child">5</span>
</div>
<button id="next" class="next">Next</button>
<button id="back" class="back">Back</button>
```

Here is a fiddle to test the code: https://jsfiddle.net/2huemrny/1/

`document.querySelector('.parent').scrollRight` is not working. How to show hidden steps?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use 'scrollIntoView' to force the display of the new active element:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('next').onclick = function(){
    var active = document.querySelector('.active');
    active.classList.remove('active');
    active.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active');
    active.nextElementSibling.scrollIntoView();

    //Show next steps
    if(document.querySelector('.active').getBoundingClientRect().right < 0){
      document.querySelector('.parent').scrollRight = 1000;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('back').onclick = function(){
    var active = document.querySelector('.active');
    active.classList.remove('active');
    active.previousElementSibling.classList.add('active');
    active.previousElementSibling.scrollIntoView();

    //Show previous steps
  }
}
```

```css
body{
    direction: rtl;
}

.parent{
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: black;
    padding: 10px;
}

.child{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    background: grey;
    margin-left: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.active{
    background: red;
}

.next{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.back{
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span class="child active">1</span>
    <span class="child">2</span>
    <span class="child">3</span>
    <span class="child">4</span>
    <span class="child">5</span>
</div>
<button id="next" class="next">Next</button>
<button id="back" class="back">Back</button>
```